# Rails uses singularized table name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails returns me the following error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "srlzd_data" does not exist
```

It seems that it uses the singularized table name, but I don't know why.
If I force the table name in my SrlzdData model with `set_table_name 'srlzd_datas'` it works, but it's a crappy workaround!

Any idea from where it could comes? (Rails 3.2.13 / Ruby 1.9.3)

```
class SrlzdData < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    attr_accessible :interests
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :setting, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :srlzd_data, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, 
                  :setting_attributes, :srlzd_data_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :setting, :srlzd_data
end
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is already a plural, your table name should be `srlzd_data`

I'd suggest renaming it via migrate.

Comment: Argh... faced to the limits of my english knowledges! I try and let you know.